# Maui Blazor, button not raising onclick event

Tags: android, maui, maui-blazor

The buttons in my Maui Blazor application, are not raising onclick events, when running on my physical, Android 11, device. However, the application works as expected on my local windows device, and my (Android 11 and higher) android emulators. Any ideas of why this might be happening? Thanks!

```
<button @onclick="Navigate">Navigate</button>

@code
{
    void Navigate ()
    {
        // Breakpoint here never hit
        NavigationManager.NavigateTo("/Destination");
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, this is `known` issue and it's been tracked in [this thread](https://github.com/dotnet/maui/issues/9882). You need to install the Webview version `105.0.5195.136` to fix the issue. Also , you can refer to [this thread](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/245837736?pli=1) for more details.